# Android: Is there a way to automatically, forcefully clear app data/cache when one downloads an update for the app from Google Play store?

Tags: android, google-play

Is there a way to automatically, forcefully clear app data/cache when one downloads an update for the app from Google Play store?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean manually? You can go to the application manager in settings and there should be an option to delete saved data and cached data.

Comment: No no, automatically.

Comment: Is it for your app or for any app?

Comment: It is my app, I have control over it

Answer (score 0):

Just save the current versionCode in the sharedPref and check if the current is newer than just delete all your data manually.

for deleting the shared pref use:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit().clear().apply();
```

or this method can be useful for delete external `getExternalStorageDirectory()` dir too:

```
            final String dirPath = context.getFilesDir().getParent() + "/shared_prefs";
            final File sharedPrefFolder = new File(dirPath);
            if (sharedPrefFolder.exists() && sharedPrefFolder.isDirectory()) {
                String[] children = sharedPrefFolder.list();
                for (String aChildren : children) {
                    new File(sharedPrefFolder, aChildren).delete();
                }
            }
```